# InetAddress withouth using Scriptlets

Tags: jsp, jstl, el, inetaddress

Is there a way to do:

```
java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()
```

without using JSP Scriptlets?
Looking for a more conventional solution, probably using JSTL capabilities to achieve this.

Take note that `${pageContext.request.*}` jstl function doesn't give me the output I want. I want the computer host name.

I tried a JavaScript but it didn't work, no idea as of why:

```
<script>document.write(java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName())</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

What output does $pageContext.request.* give you and how is it not what you want?

Is ${pageContext.request.localName} not what you want?

Comment: `java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()` gives me for example "link_boy" host string (computer host name) when I'm running the app with the following url "http://localhost/app"
`pageContext.request.localName` gives me "localhost" as host name

Answer (score 0):

InetAddress doesn't have a public constructor which stops it from accessing it using jsp:useBean.

If you really want to get rid of scriplets,

- you can pass the value from the backend as a response
- write a custom class to get the value and access the class using jsp:useBean